# How do I beat the Homestead Innkeeper at Six Men's Morris?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I've drained about 500 of my precious in game currency trying to beat the Innkeeper of the Inn in the Homestead area for an achievement. Is there a trick to beating this guy? He is like the Six Men's Morris world champion or something and has already caused me so much rage.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-r8YuMNUrU This is a surefire way to win nearly 90% of the time!

Answer (score 3):

1. Play first
2. Place your first two pieces on the middle square at the top left and bottom right corners
3. Switch to blocking the opponent from getting 3 in a row (a *'mill'*) for a couple of moves
4. When you get a free move (i.e. you don't have to block) try to make a mill (line of 3)
5. During steps 3 and 4 keep blocking/moving with a view to getting two mills that you can move between.
6. Don't lose any pieces.
7. If you get to a place where you can keep moving to complete a mill (ideally between two) you can use it to mop up all his pieces.
8. You can break a mill and then re-complete it in two moves - if your opponent is more than 2 moves away from completing a mill you can use this to stop him too.

Here's a winning set up:

[image: Set up to win]

The top middle white piece can move up and down between two mills - at this point they can keep repeating to remove all black's pieces.

Here is a [video with more detail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-r8YuMNUrU).

Answer (score 0):

Download a 9 man morris app and play 2nd on the game and put his moves in the and do the moves the app does(make sure the apps on the hardest mode)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just got it for the first time after like an hour. You have to play second, get it so that you end up 3 chips each with it being your turn, move your middle chip in the row you made to an adjacent corner. When he moves, create a row by moving one of the outside chips to the row he did not block.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your description. Where abouts on the board would your three chips be? Surely that is an important detail to add in...